# Is the ANTLR parser generated by ANTLR itself?

Tags: parsing, antlr

Does ANTLR parse grammar files by using a parser generated by ANTLR?

I tried googling but didn't find answer to the question.

Comment: Did you even read the source code? https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/tree/v4.11.1/tool/src/org/antlr/v4/parse

Comment: The Antlr4 tool uses the Antlr3 tool and runtime, not Antlr4. There is some talk of having the Antlr4 tool bootstrapped with a generated Antlr4 parser, but it's not being developed. In lieu of an official Antlr4 grammar in Antlr4, there is a version, and older versions, [here](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/antlr). The [antlr4](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/antlr/antlr4) grammar is used in several third-party tools. Also, please do not use a derogatory term to describe the software. It is offensive. It has bugs, but all software does.

Comment: @kaby76 not sure if Kari meant it as a derogatory term. I've heard the term [eating your own dog food](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eating_your_own_dog_food) before, and I never got the impression it had a negative connotation...

Comment: I’d add that I interpret “Eating your own dog food” as positive.  It’s the process of using your tool yourself to ensure it’s really useful (a good thing)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does. ANTLR4 comes with a [full batch of ANTLR4 grammars](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/tree/master/tool/src/org/antlr/v4/parse) for building itself. This is why it still requires an existing parser for the build process.